# FFProbe as .NET Process gives error while command line does not

Tags: c#, ffmpeg, command-line, process

I've got a sample mp4 (a copy can be found [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1C143equHX_-712z3eYIT6AmjAlsAoLj1/view?usp=sharing) [sample_tagged.mp4, 562KB]) I've tagged with metadata using FFMpeg. Using a command line, if I issue a general command to view the metadata, I get everything.

```
> ffprobe.exe -hide_banner -loglevel error -show_entries 'format_tags' sample_tagged.mp4
[FORMAT]
TAG:minor_version=512
TAG:major_brand=isom
TAG:compatible_brands=isomiso2avc1mp41
TAG:IMDB=tt0012345
TAG:Title=Sample MP4
TAG:synopsis=Watch MP4 sample
TAG:Rating=3.30
TAG:TMDB=tv/12345
TAG:Subtitle=Samples for all!
TAG:year=2000
TAG:date=2000:01:01T00:00:00
TAG:ReleaseDate=2000:01:01
TAG:genre=Beach;Windy;Sample
TAG:encoder=Lavf60.3.100
[/FORMAT]
```

Also using the command line, if I limit it to a specific tag, I only get the specific tag as expected.

```
> ffprobe.exe -hide_banner -loglevel error -show_entries 'format_tags=TMDB' sample_tagged.mp4
[FORMAT]
TAG:TMDB=tv/12345
[/FORMAT]
```

I've set up a C# Process (in LINQPad) to mimic this behavior and return the results as a collection of key/value pairs.

```
async Task Main()
{
  var sample = await FFProbe.GetProperties("sample_tagged.mp4");
  sample.Dump("Sample");

  var targeted = await FFProbe.GetProperties("sample_tagged.mp4", "TMDB");
  targeted.Dump("Sample Targeted");
}

class FFProbe
{
  const string _exeName = @"ffprobe.exe";
  const string _arguments = @"-hide_banner -loglevel error -show_entries 'format_tags{0}' ""{1}""";

  static Encoding _Utf8NoBOM = new UTF8Encoding(false);

  public static async Task<ICollection<KeyValuePair<string, string>>> GetProperties(string filename, params string[] targetProperties)
  {
    using (var probe = new Process())
    {
      var propsRead = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();

      probe.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
      probe.OutputDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
      {
        e.Dump("Output");
        if (e?.Data is null)
          return;
        
        if (e.Data.StartsWith("TAG"))
        {
          var eq = e.Data.IndexOf('=');

          if (eq > 1)
          {
            var key = e.Data.Substring(4, eq - 4);
            var value = e.Data.Substring(eq + 1).Trim();

            if (!targetProperties.Any() || targetProperties.Any(tp => key.Equals(tp, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)))
            {
              if (value.Contains("\\r\\n"))
                value = value.Replace("\\r\\n", Environment.NewLine);

              propsRead.Add(new KeyValuePair<string, string>(key, value));
            }
          }
        }
      };
      probe.ErrorDataReceived += (object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e) =>
      {
        e.Dump("Error");
        if (e?.Data is null)
          return;
      };

      probe.StartInfo.FileName = _exeName;
      
      var tagLimiter = string.Empty;
      
      if (targetProperties.Any())
        tagLimiter = $"={string.Join(',', targetProperties)}";
      
      var arguments = string.Format(_arguments, tagLimiter, filename);
      arguments.Dump();

      probe.StartInfo.Arguments = arguments;
      probe.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
      probe.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
      probe.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
      probe.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
      probe.StartInfo.StandardOutputEncoding = _Utf8NoBOM;
      probe.StartInfo.StandardErrorEncoding = _Utf8NoBOM;

      probe.Start();
      probe.BeginOutputReadLine();
      probe.BeginErrorReadLine();
      
      await probe.WaitForExitAsync();

      return propsRead;
    }
  }
}
```

The output for the full sample dump matches the full metadata list. But when getting the targeted tag, I get two error responses.

```
No match for section 'format_tags=TMDB'
Failed to set value ''format_tags=TMDB'' for option 'show_entries': Invalid argument
```

From the output, the arguments sent into the process match those of the command line above:

```
-hide_banner -loglevel error -show_entries 'format_tags=TMDB' "sample_tagged.mp4"
```

I've copy/pasted the generated arguments to the command line call and it returns the value expected.

What am I missing and/or need correction in setting up the call to get the same results via a Process as the command line?